# Jmeter different loop count for every user

Tags: java, testing, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to extract some IDs using Regular Expression Extractor after a GET request, but every new user have different number of IDs after his GET request e.g. a single thread(user) has 10 teacher IDs so I can get Ids by putting a regular expression extractor in a loop with 10 iterations but when there are 100 users and every user has different count of IDs then how can I use my loop here?

Comment: Show us relevant code and examples of your requests.

Comment: let me put an example here:
Thread groups: 10
GET landing page
GET log-in
POST log-in
GET api call
(from here I need to get teacher IDs and every "School Principal" user has different number of teachers)

Answer (score 0):

I think that [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) is what you're looking for. Basing on Regular Expression Extractor match count it can generate different subsequent requests for each virtual user.

See [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter) guide for demo of using Regular Expression Extractor in conjunction with ForEach Controller.